# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 - Setup Blocked

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2015 Update 3  from offline installer (iso file) and get this error:

[image]

I am running on window seven an i do have Visual Studio 2013 Update 2013 on my system.

Here is some log:

```
    [0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:07]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:07]i000: MUX:  Wait for View to be loaded
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:07]i000: MUX:  View loaded
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:07]i000: MUX:  Checking for update...
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:07]i000: MUX:  Setup update feature is enabled. Evaluating conditions to determine whether to run setup update.
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:07]i000: MUX:  Checking http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=659005 for update.
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:11]i000: MUX:  Failed to download the update xml file from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=659005 Setup will not be updated.
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:11]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:11]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:11]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:11]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:11]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:11]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:11]i052: Condition '(CurrentOperation = "Install") OR (CurrentOperation = "Repair")' evaluates to true.
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:11]i000: MUX:  Configuring feed...
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:11]i000: MUX:  Stop Block: NoApplicableUpdates : Update 3 requires a member of the Visual Studio 2015 family to be present or is blocked by another condition on your computer.
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:11]i000: MUX:  Online feed url authoring not found
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:11]i000: MUX:  Stop Block: NoApplicableUpdates : Update 3 requires a member of the Visual Studio 2015 family to be present or is blocked by another condition on your computer.
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:11]i000: MUX:  Go to Blocker page.
[0E68:1238][2016-07-05T17:24:11]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
```

Comment: It tells you that you should have Visual Studio 2015 installed (not Visual Studio 2013)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You've downloaded the offline installer for the Update. This offline installer will update a previous version of Visual studio **2015** to Update 3. Major Visual Studio versions are installed side-by-side. So your 2013 installation will be left untouched by the 2015 update installer

You'll need to download the offline installer of "Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3" or  first install "Visual Studio 2015 RTM" and then apply the update you've downloaded.

Comment: I am encountering the same error and definitely already have VS2015 installed (currently VS2015 Update 1).  What's odd here is the line: "MUX:  Failed to download the update xml file from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=659005 Setup will not be updated".

Visiting that URL in a browser redirects to a generic MS download page rather than returning anything useful, so it appears there is currently an issue with Microsoft's download site.

Answer (score 11):

I faced a similar if not the same issue. I installed *VS2015 with Update 3*. There was no other VS version or edition in the PC - so you can say this is a *fresh* install. On starting VS, it prompted me to get KB3165756 (14.0.25431.0) and the next thing I got was: -

*"Setup Blocked - Update 3 requires a member of the Visual Studio 2015 family to be present or is blocked by another condition on your computer"*

Here is what I did to get around the problem -

1. From the command prompt, type *"vs14-kb3165756 /uninstall"*. (Don't use the */repair* option as this won't work.)
2. Choose Repair.
3. Let it run until finish.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get vs14-kb3165756 is not recognized as internal or external command error either in normal cmd and vs2015 command prompt?

Comment: Ok got it, we need to get into directory where the vs14-kb3165756.exe resides.

Comment: Works for me, BTW, ``vs14-kb3165756.exe`` is the Visual Studio Setup Launcher Setup executable program, which is named ``VS2015.2.exe`` in my download.

Comment: "windows cannot find  vs14-kb3165756"

Answer (score 1):

Solved by running the Original installation ISO.
Setup auto-detect what will be updated, what will be replaced before starting the installation/upgrades (without touching what it's already installed).

Answer (score 1):

Download another version of vs2015 solve my problem, reference to:

[How to download Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 (not 2017)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290672/how-to-download-visual-studio-community-edition-2015-not-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Using the Visual Studio Web Installer handled it by installing what was required vs. finding which ISO to use.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix Visual Studio 2015 versions. I had the same problem because I tried to install the VS2015 Update 3 over a VS2015 Professional Update 2. If you are using the regular, Professional or Enterprise version then keep using the same VS 'flavor'.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508386/8769139

Works for me by using this command `vsupdate_KB3022398/uninstall`  in your download directory, then click "repair"