# How to download Visual Studio Community Edition 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a Resharper 9x license and it is only compatible up to MS VS Community 2015 edition. I tried to download the 2015 version from Microsoft but their website stubbornly wants me to have 2017, only. Can someone please provide me a url to the 2015 edition? Or, explain how to navigate Microsoft's site to obtain the 2015 edition?

**Update on solution**

1) vs_community.exe is the download filename for any version, 2015, 2017, etc. You will not know which version it is until you click the .exe. You will then see the version in the title of the installer.

2) There is a url trick to get the version that you want.

<s>https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15</s>

...change the rel=15 to rel=17 etc

Or use the links provided in the answer below

Comment: "url trick" link does not work any more. The links in the actual answer do.

Answer (score 713, accepted):

You can use these links to download Visual Studio 2015

- Community Edition: [`vs2015.3.com_enu.iso`](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615448)

And for anyone in the future who might be looking for the other editions here are the links for them as well:

- Professional Edition: [`vs2015.3.pro_enu.iso`](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615434)
- Enterprise Edition: [`vs2015.3.ent_enu.iso`](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615436)

Comment: Thanks for the iso, as my company firewall prevents the download in the Visual studio web installer.

Comment: Wow, they're offering an ISO of the 2015 community edition?  They claim that they don't.

Comment: Life saver. I was searching for at least an hour before I found this. MS has wiped the earth of VS2015 downloads. I'm surprised these links still work.

Comment: Thank you sir, for being more effective than the moronic conglomerate that is Microsoft.

Comment: The web installer of the community version now automatically updates and offers to install versions of VS2017. The ISO link still seems to work.

Comment: very very helpful. Can't find a link to download it from anywhere else and got it from here.

Comment: Nice. If you go the "official" route through the download page of the latest release and go for the older versions you have to login (or create an account and then login) so that you get to the actual download. This reminds me of how the Qt Company screwed things up with the mandatory account thing for downloading the Qt SDK through their official installer (luckily we have all the binaries provided by so many Linux distros out there).

Comment: How to check md5sum of that iso file?

Comment: I'm glad I got VS Enterprise 2015 from the college store before I graduated. I still use it. I don't care if it's no longer officially supported.

Comment: @rbaleksandar Gheez! [Qt](https://www.qt.io/pricing) Designer is $990/yr. Qt for Application Development (desktop and mobile) is $3,950/yr.  ‎Embarcadero [Rad Studio](https://www.embarcadero.com/app-development-tools-store/rad-studio) Pro is $2,599 once, then $599/yr. Rad Studio Enterprise is $4,599 once, then $1,199/yr. The Architect Edition is $6,599, then $2,183.yr. Most of these tool developers have become _rent seekers_ . They expect developers to shore up their quarterly reports with a constant revenue stream.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise is $3,000/yr for a [subscription](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/pricing/#tab-b8953f16f0b68f60f18) (_rent_). A [perpetual](https://www.componentsource.com/product/microsoft-visual-studio-enterprise/prices) license is $8,931, then $1,639/yr for a MSDN subscription.

Comment: Thank you! The Web Installer of the professional edition didn't work for me (keeps complaining about missing packages), but the ISO is downloading.

Comment: I get this error: "a setup package is either missing or damaged"

Comment: you can download the ISO instead to avoid that error @RonyTesler, I got that too previously

Comment: Unfortunately, while using the custom install method the community web installer at least doesn't appear to include .NET desktop environment (C#), though it does web and mobile tools. The closest option for C# is Xamarin for mobile development. However, I'm testing out the default install method (using ISO, as mentioned above).

Comment: After many failed attempts from other versions of the ISO, the pro link here worked for me.

Comment: Community edition links didn't work for me. Looks like the web installer points to inexisting urls and the iso points to vs 2015 Shell. Removing the last query parameter in the iso URL, downloaded the actual VS 2015 iso installer for me. (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615448)

Answer (score 29):

The "official" way to get the vs2015 is to go to https://my.visualstudio.com/ ; join the " Visual Studio Dev Essentials" and then search the relevant file to download https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Visual%20Studio%202015%20with%20Update%203

Comment: Sure, you can, but the "correct answer" is the one with 95% of the upvotes.

Comment: This hasn't worked for a long time and is NOT the "correct" answer if you're actually trying to help other developers. The search comes up empty, even if you've joined "Visual Studio Dev Essentials".

Comment: I can't do that since it keeps saying that I have to rejoin Dev Essentials. The correct answer, however helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The toxicity in this community - this is the answer: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/

You can find it by searching for "Visual Studio 2015 Community installer" - it was the first link in the search engine I used.

It's easy to find - nothing difficult - no moronic conglomerate trying to stop you from downloading a community/free edition of their product. You can see that they allow downloading all the way back to the 2013 version (and so much more).

There is a nice big text box that lets you type in what you are looking for right on the link I provided - try typing "Visual Studio 2015".

The correct answer isn't a link that's deep in the Microsoft download folder that could move and no longer be correct.

The correct answer (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/) gives you a selection of ways and versions to download (iso, web installer, shell, etc) [image: Visual Studio 2015 download page]

If you don't want to create an account just use a throw-away account - use a guid and create a (insert your favorite webmail provider here) account that you never use again.

Comment: This now shows up as "Unavailable" for me.

Comment: That link does work for me, but there's no Community Edition in that list.

Comment: Downloading is requiring a purchased subscription.  Looks like the toxicity will remain