# Installing dlib with python 3.8 windows 10 error

Tags: python, cmake, dlib

I cant install dlib on python with cmd , I have downloaded cmake and putted it on PATH, or is there any plugin i have to download it first ? Or does my pip's environment is located at a wrong place ? Or do I have to change my python to 64 bit instead of 32 bit ? If I have to do so , please let me know the way to do it , I am a newbie

```
C:\Users\Yusuf>python -m pip install dlib --user
Collecting dlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/92/05c3b98636661cb80d190a5a777dd94effcc14c0f6893222e5ca81e74fbc/dlib-19.19.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Yusuf\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lpo7_ajq\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Yusuf\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lpo7_ajq\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Yusuf\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0h0t6gan\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=
         cwd: C:\Users\Yusuf\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lpo7_ajq\dlib\
    Complete output (65 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Yusuf\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lpo7_ajq\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Yusuf\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lpo7_ajq\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Yusuf\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lpo7_ajq\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8'
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
    -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.24.28314.0
    -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.24.28314.0
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Found PythonInterp: C:/Program Files (x86)/Python38-32/python.exe (found version "3.8")
    CMake Error at C:/Users/Yusuf/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-lpo7_ajq/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:124 (message):
      Python config failure: Python is 32-bit, chosen compiler is 64-bit
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      C:/Users/Yusuf/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-lpo7_ajq/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:16 (find_package)
      C:/Users/Yusuf/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-lpo7_ajq/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:33 (include)


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/Yusuf/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-lpo7_ajq/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Yusuf\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lpo7_ajq\dlib\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
        setup(
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Yusuf\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lpo7_ajq\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\Yusuf\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lpo7_ajq\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Yusuf\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lpo7_ajq\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Yusuf\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lpo7_ajq\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Yusuf\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lpo7_ajq\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Yusuf\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lpo7_ajq\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Yusuf\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lpo7_ajq\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Yusuf\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0h0t6gan\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix= Check the logs for full command output.
```

Please help me thank you !

Comment: refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54285268/getting-error-in-installing-dlib-using-pip)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NOTE:First make sure you have installed c++ compilers and cmake Then start following the sptes:

1. go to [dlib on github](https://github.com/davisking/dlib)
2. click on clone or download button and then download the package manually by clicking on the zip download And after the download finished , extract the file and put it in desktop

3.Then open Powershell or cmd

4.type in the command `cd C:/users/(your username)/Desktop/master-dlib/master-dlib`

5.Then when you changed your current working directory then type in the command `python setup.py install`

**NOTE2: This is the manual way but also look into [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54285268/getting-error-in-installing-dlib-using-pip) Too.**

Answer (score 0):

1. go to [python.org](https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/) copy link location of latest binary executable or binary specific to your python version .
2. in cmd prompt type`python -m pip install`  +paste link location.
3. now run your .py file having dlib .