# cannot install web deploy on windows server, installer does not find either "visual studio 2015 update 2" and "visual studio 2015"

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, webdeploy

I'm trying to install web deploy for IIS, on my windows 8 machine, but the installer cannot find "visual studio update 2" and then fails. I'm using visual studio 2017, does this mean I need to install VS 2015 as well?

neither directly from the IIS application nor the web installer work.

Answer (score 0):

ok if anyone runs into this problem my solution was to download visual studio 2015, you can find the links here

[How to download Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 (not 2017)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290672/how-to-download-visual-studio-community-edition-2015-not-2017)