# VS 2015 update 3 installation block

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying install VS 2015 update 3 in my computer. and I am getting Error like this.
[image]

I have already install VS 2019 and 2017 professional.
[Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 - Setup Blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185466/visual-studio-2015-update-3-setup-blocked/39508386)
won't work for me.
I have tried to install both LTR and update 3 version. same error getting.

Is that cause be the VS 2019 & VS 2017 prior installation?
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> Is that cause be the VS 2019 & VS 2017 prior installation?

The answer is probably yes.

First clean the installation of any other VS versions and then reinstall VS 2015 Update 3.

To clean VS, open command prompt as admin and run the following commands:

```
C:\> cd "Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer"
```

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer>InstallCleanup.exe
```